# Как в данном коде работает команда CDQ?

Tags: c++, ассемблер, x86

Дана ассемблерная вставка на C++. Не могу разобраться, как (именно в данном случае) работает команда cdq: какие регистры изменяет, что и куда записывает и т. п.

```
mov eax, a;
mov ebx, b;
add eax, ebx;
mov ebx, c;
imul eax, ebx;
mov ebx, d;
sub eax, ebx;
mov ebx, e;
cdq;
idiv ebx;
mov x, eax;
```

Comment: Гуглите любой справочник команд, вот на первой странице поисковой выдачи: https://sysprog.ru/post/komandy-cbw-cwd-cwde-cdq

Comment: Если в ЕАХ лежит положительное число, то CDQ забивает нулями регистр EDX. Если-же в ЕАХ отрицательное число, то EDX заполняется единицами.

Comment: А можно поподробнее, зачем заполнять EDX нулями или единицами? Что это даёт?

Comment: Инструкция деления DIV устроена так, что делимое должно быть в 2-раза больше, чем делитель. Например если делитель 32-битный и лежит в ЕВХ (как в вашем примере), то делимое обязательно должно быть 64-битным, и как-раз в регистровой паре EDX:EAX.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Спасли меня